# Reference not showing paper title

Tags: bibtex, achemso

[enter link description here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ej372jxsjx2s8em/myCitations.bib?dl=0)I am a new user of Latex.

I am writing a paper for an ACS journal where the references are required to show the paper TITLE. I am using bibdesk for managing my citations. But when i typeset, the references do not contain the title of the paper.

Can someone please help me what i can do to include the titles in the references?

```
\documentclass[journal=jpccck,manuscript=article,etalmode=truncate,maxauthors=0]{achemso}
\setkeys{acs}{etalmode=truncate,maxauthors=0}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem} % Formula subscripts using \ce{}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{mciteplus}

\begin{document}

\bibliography{myCitations}

\end{document}
```

[[image: The results look like this]][1

But i need the paper title after the author's list.

Thanks in advance.

%-------------------------------

"myCitations" is a bibtex file. Image of a reference under this file looks like - [image]

and i cite them as

`\cite{JACS_Wilner96}`

Comment: I think we would need to know how is this reference written in `myCitations` and how do you cite it.

Comment: Works fine for me. Have you checked if your references contain a title

Comment: Hi, I have added an image of my "myCitations" file and the way i cite is \cite{JACS_Wilner96}

Comment: `\setkeys{acs}{articletitle = true}`

Comment: Hi @Johannes_B, The output says, Package xkeyval error: 'articletitle undefined in families "acs". '

Comment: @RudFaden, Yes they do

Comment: Could you put up a copy of your bibtex file.

Comment: Please check if your version of achemso is up-to-date. Current is `2015/04/07 v3.10 Submission to ACS journals`

Comment: By the way, the achemso will adjust your files anyway. There is no real use in fiddling around stuff that will get fixed by the publisher.

Comment: @RudFaden Please find a copy here. https://www.dropbox.com/s/ej372jxsjx2s8em/myCitations.bib?dl=0

Comment: @Johannes_B I thought so too, but the editor asked for it.

Comment: Did you check for updates? Putting `\listfiles` at the very beginning of your document will print the file list and the dates to the end of the log file.

Comment: @Johannes_B Here is the log file. I would really appreciate if you take a look. https://www.dropbox.com/s/kh2y1w8bitgj95v/MSH_KB_Manuscript_JPC.log?dl=0

Comment: TeX Live 2011 is very outdated. Maybe the option wasn't available back then. I recommend updateing to TeX Live 2015, but an update is always some kind of a risk.

Comment: Your log shows `achemso 2011/03/11 v3.5g`: that's massively out-of-date. To keep up with journal requirements there are regular updates to the clas:s you'll need a new version from [CTAN](http://ctan.org/pkg/achemso).

Comment: I can compile the references with no error. So the best guess is that it is due to a outdated version.

Comment: @JosephWright Can you please direct me to the link to an updated version?

Comment: @RudFaden Can you please direct me to the link to an updated version?

Comment: You can find it [here](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/achemso). But you should properly also update texlive

Comment: Thank you very much guys. The updated version seems to be working now.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved by updating.